# matplotlib: Why is my Y-Axis distorting?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The statement that I use to plot my MovingAverages, `ax1.plot(xLength[-SP:], Av1[-SP:], '#fa32e3', linewidth=1.5)`,  is causing my y-axis ticks to go beyond the end of the plot window. As a result, I am unable to eliminate clutter at the upper end of the y-axis by using `prune` to get rid of the top tick label.

If you comment `ax1.plot(xLength[-SP:], Av1[-SP:], '#fa32e3', linewidth=1.5)` out, the y-axis ticks display correctly allowing me to prune the top tick label (top tick label = 5.0).

What is causing the strange y-axis tick behavior? How can I properly display my y-axis ticks when plotting MovingAverages, so I may `prune` the uppermost y-axis tick label '4.8'?

My chart without plotting MovingAverages displaying the correct y-axis pre-prune:
[image]
My chart after plotting MovingAverages. Notice how the y-axis has shifted (and is no longer prune-able):
[image]

Here is a chopped down code version:

```
    # Visualize my stock data

import numpy as np
import time
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.finance import _candlestick
import matplotlib
import pylab
matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 9})


eachStock = ['AMD']


def movingAverage(values, window):
    weights = np.repeat(1.0, window)/window
    smas = np.convolve(values, weights, 'valid')
    return smas


def graphData(stock, MA1, MA2):
    try:
        stockFile = 'AMD.txt'
        date, closep, highp, lowp, openp, volume = np.loadtxt(stockFile, delimiter=',',unpack=True,
                                                              converters={ 0: mdates.bytespdate2num('%Y%m%d')})

        xLength = range(len(date))          # length of the x-axis used for plotting coordinates (xLength, y)
        SP = len(date[MA2-1:])              # Right hand stopping point so MAs align with CandleStix
        candleAr = list(zip(xLength,openp,closep,highp,lowp,volume)) # The data set



        # Formatter Class to eliminate weekend data gaps on chart
        class Jackarow(mdates.DateFormatter):
            def __init__(self, fmt):
                mdates.DateFormatter.__init__(self, fmt)
            def __call__(self, x, pos=0):
                # This gets called even when out of bounds, so IndexError must be prevented.
                if x < 0:
                    x = 0
                elif x >= len(date):
                    x = -1
                return mdates.DateFormatter.__call__(self, date[int(x)], pos)


        fig = plt.figure(facecolor='#07000D')


# The CANDLESTICK plot
        ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 4), (1,0), rowspan=4, colspan=4, axisbg='#07000D')
        _candlestick(ax1, candleAr[-SP:], width=.75, colorup='#53c156', colordown='#ff1717')

        # Format Colors, Axis, and the like
        ax1.grid(True, color='w')
        ax1.yaxis.label.set_color('w')

        # My Broken Pruner
        plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(prune='upper'))

        ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(10))
        ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(Jackarow('%Y-%m-%d'))
        ax1.spines['bottom'].set_color("#5998ff")
        ax1.spines['top'].set_color("#5998ff")
        ax1.spines['left'].set_color("#5998ff")
        ax1.spines['right'].set_color("#5998ff")
        ax1.tick_params(axis='y', colors='w')
        ax1.tick_params(axis='x', colors='w')

        plt.ylabel('Stock Price')



# Plot Moving Averages
        Av1 = movingAverage(closep, MA1)

##################################################################
########## This is causing the problem with the prune  ###########

        ax1.plot(xLength[-SP:], Av1[-SP:], '#fa32e3', linewidth=1.5)

##################################################################
##################################################################




        plt.suptitle(stock, color='w')
        plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
        plt.subplots_adjust(left=.10, bottom=.14, right=.93, top=.95, wspace=.20, hspace=0)

        plt.show()
        fig.savefig('savedChart.png', facecolor=fig.get_facecolor())


    except Exception as e:
        print('failed main loop',str(e))

for stock in eachStock:
    graphData(stock, 13, 50) # These numbers correspond to the Moving Average lengths
```

and the data set 'AMD.txt' is available here: http://pastebin.com/CJm7n3y1

Comment: Are you sure you are operating on the correct axes?  `plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(prune='upper'))` could be grabbing the wrong one?

Comment: I am fairly certain I am operating on the correct y-axis. If I change the prune value of `plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(prune='upper'))` to either `prune='lower'` or `prune='both'` the lower Stock Price tick of 1.6 is removed, but never the upper.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a copy-pastable example?  The locators are allowed to return tick locations off the edge, this may be a bug in the prune logic.  I am also confused by what `get_ylim()` returns, you say it is [1.5, 5.0], but the top/bottom ticks are at [1.6, 4.8].

Comment: I have updated my post with a copy-pastable example.

Comment: I've read your post 5 times, and tried several things with your code, but I still don't understand what the actual problem is :)

Comment: I need my `prune` function to work so I can get rid of the top y-axis tick label. The whole chart looks like this: http://imgur.com/He0F7fm   I want to get rid of the '4.8' tick label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the axis limits and ticks/tick labels explicitly using
`plt.axis([xLength[0], xLength[-1], ax1.get_ylim()[0], ax1.get_ylim()[1]])`
and then prune the resulting axis with
`plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(prune='upper'))`

Now my Chart is displaying the correct axis ticks/tick labels, and I am able to `prune` the desired values.